# Send a print job to a printer using its IP address through Python program

Tags: python, flask, printing

I have build a flask based web app. The problem I am facing is to send a print job to different printers through their IP addresses, already configured with my windows based server where application is running. I am facing difficulty in finding the right library and method to fulfill the requirement.

I have tried some libraries such as socket, cups, win32print but I might not be doing it right.

It would be really helpful if you can guide me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You probably don't want CUPS (it's for Linux / Unix / macOS) or sockets (too low-level). `win32printing` sounds more promising. What code did you try?